# ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U7'), dtype('float64')) -> None

Tags: python

I am trying to create a graph of the relationship between the features and the response using scatterplots and I keep getting this error ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U7'), dtype('float64')) -> None

here is my code:

```
g=sns.pairplot(finalcoaches, x_vars=['Capacity','GSR','WinPer2022'],
             y_vars='TotalPay', height=4, aspect=1, kind='reg'
              )

plt.subplots_adjust(top=.85)
g.fig.suptitle('Total Pay vs. Capacity, GSR, 2022 Win Percentage',fontsize = 18)
```

I am not sure what the issue is.